# Angular Routing routerLinkActive class not getting removed from base page even on other link routing

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am providing a simple routing example which works well. The only issue is that **routerLinkActive** is adding class 'baboossa' to whichever link is active. When I go from home to other links as 'about' or 'window' the link gets orange (due to baboossa class), but I can still see home also to be orange. Why now I am having 2 links with added classes from **routerLinkActive** and class is not getting removed from home?

**app.component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li><a [routerLink]="''" routerLinkActive="baboossa">Home</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="'/about'" routerLinkActive="baboossa">About</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="'/window'" routerLinkActive="baboossa">Window</a></li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path:'', component: HomeComponent},
    {path:'about', component: AboutComponent},
    {path:'window', component:WindowComponent}
  ])
]
```

**styles.css**

```
.baboossa {background:orange;}
```

Results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can someone point out the problem why I am getting 2 orange backgrounds on other active links than baseone (home)?

[image]

Comment: `{path:'', component: HomeComponent}` should be `{path:'', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }`

Comment: tried, did not work. Same result.

Comment: change `{path:'', component: HomeComponent}` to `{path:'home', component: HomeComponent}`

Comment: thanks @AbhishekEkaanth - this worked. I created one more line with this along with 1st default blank routing -- this worked well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can archive with two methods:

1. Add routerLinkActiveOptions `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` with routerLinkActive.

Like this :
`[routerLink]="''" [routerLinkActive]="['baboossa']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"`.

2. Redirect your empty router `path : ''` to any particular path like '{ path : '', redirectTo: 'home'} in your router module.

Like this :

```
[{
    path: '',    
    pathMatch : 'full',
    redirectTo: 'home'
},
{
    path: 'home',    
    component: HomeComponent
}]
```

and change `[routerLink]="''"` with `[routerLink]="'home'"`.

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsagmd)

Comment: More information on this approach is in the [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/router#routerlinkactive-binding).

Answer (score 2):

I think you can check below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-jufxu8?file=app/app.routing.module.ts

For more [Angular Routing](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you can do it with a named path as default instead of empty. The RESTful API approach in which URL's are easy to understand.

```
<ul>
  <li><a [routerLink]="[ 'home' ]" routerLinkActive="baboossa">Home</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="[ 'about' ]" routerLinkActive="baboossa">About</a></li>
  <li><a [routerLink]="'[ 'window' ]" routerLinkActive="baboossa">Window</a></li>
</ul>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And then

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path:'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path:'about', component: AboutComponent},
    {path:'window', component:WindowComponent}
    {path:'**', redirectTo: 'home'}
  ])
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used bootstrap for my nav bar and this code below worked perfect without changing the class. `routerLinkActive="active"` should do it.

````
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/followers">Followers</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/posts">Posts</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. But i want to empty path when i was in home.

And i dont want to use **[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"** because when i am in **questions/:questionsId** question menu in not active.

Like: abc.com

not: abc.com/home

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }, { path: 'questions/:questionsId', component: QuestionsComponent }, { path: 'questions', component: QuestionsComponent }];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                           <ul>
                             <li>
                                <a
                                  [routerLinkActive]="'active'"
                                  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true}"
                                  routerLink="/">
                                  <p>All Students</p>
                                </a>
                              </li>

                              <li>
                                <a
                                  [routerLinkActive]="'active'
                                   [routerLink]="'/addstudent'">
                                  <p>Add New Student</p>
                                </a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>






const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'addstudent', component: AddNewStudentComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },

];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).